# Is my WCF security working?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, visual-studio, security

I'm using Message Security in my wcf service.

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="GenericWsBinding" closeTimeout="00:45:00" openTimeout="00:45:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:45:00" sendTimeout="00:45:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="true"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

My doubt is, is my service secured with just the three line below:

```
<security mode="Message">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" />
  </security>
```

Or am I missing something ? Obs: I am using datacontract and datamember with my types, since messagecontract needs exclusivity

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose "Message" security mode, you should define parameters in "message" element. Your "transport" element will be probably ignored and your service will take default parameters for missing "message".

Alternatively you can decide to use Transport or mixed security

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms731884%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I'm little confused. I understood about the xml element being incorrect, and I changed to the correct element(message). But, how can I be sure the security is working ?

Comment: By setting security mode in web.config you force message encrypting or whole SSL transport. You can check how your data is transferred using eg. Wireshark tool.

Comment: For transport mode you should also configure your IIS web site: SSL setting -> require